# Log python http server output to file

Tags: linux, python, io-redirection, background-process, webserver

I want to start a python webserver in the background and log all of its output to file.
Instead the the servers output appears in the terminal.
Even tho i guess this is pretty basic ... I've got no clue why this isnt working.

server.py (from the python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

start command:

```
python http_server.py > server.log &
```

Why does this not output to the file and how would I do it correctly?

Comment: Are you seeing output to that shell's terminal or elsewhere?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes exactly. Its in the terminal instead.

Comment: Perhaps the program is writing to stderr; you're only redirecting stdout. Try `python http_server.py &> server.log &`